# Show last 7 days without week-end days (php)

Tags: php

I need to show last seven day  in a select box but  without week end day, in php

my  code

```
 for($time=0; $time<(86400*14); $time+=86400)
{
 ?> <option value="<?php echo $date=date('Y-n-j', time()-$time);?>"><?php echo        $date=date('n/j', time()-$time);?></option>
 <?php

}
 ?>
```

Comment: OK, so do it. Come back when you have a question.

Comment: A hint: You can find the day of week with the `N` format character. This will give 1 (monday) through 7 (sunday). If greater than 5, skip this day and the previous (next in the loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$date = date('Y-n-j');
$time = time();
while($i<7){
   if(date('D', $time)!='Sun' && date('D', $time)!='Sat'){
      $i++; 
?>
      <option value="<?php echo $date; ?>"><?php echo $date; ?></option>
<?php
   }
   $time-= 86400;
   $date = date('Y-n-j', $time);
} ?>
```